# computer lagging badly

Tags: drivers, graphics

after completely removing windows and installing ubuntu 13.04 i am experiencing extreme lag, it takes a few seconds to open apps and video playback just seems to laggy to watch, i looked up the problem and it seems to be drivers for my graphics card which is Sis i have posted the output of lspci

```
ashley@ashley-Sorrento:~$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Silicon Integrated Systems [SiS] 671MX
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Silicon Integrated Systems [SiS] AGP Port (virtual PCI-to-PCI bridge)
00:02.0 ISA bridge: Silicon Integrated Systems [SiS] SiS968 [MuTIOL Media IO] (rev 01)
00:03.0 USB controller: Silicon Integrated Systems [SiS] USB 1.1 Controller (rev 0f)
00:03.1 USB controller: Silicon Integrated Systems [SiS] USB 1.1 Controller (rev 0f)
00:03.3 USB controller: Silicon Integrated Systems [SiS] USB 2.0 Controller
00:04.0 Ethernet controller: Silicon Integrated Systems [SiS] 191 Gigabit Ethernet Adapter (rev 02)
00:05.0 IDE interface: Silicon Integrated Systems [SiS] SATA Controller / IDE mode (rev 03)
00:0f.0 Audio device: Silicon Integrated Systems [SiS] Azalia Audio Controller
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Silicon Integrated Systems [SiS] 771/671 PCIE VGA Display Adapter (rev 10)
```

im completely new so could someone help please

output of ps ax

```
ashley@ashley-Sorrento:~$ ps ax
  PID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
    1 ?        Ss     0:01 /sbin/init
    2 ?        S      0:00 [kthreadd]
    3 ?        S      0:00 [ksoftirqd/0]
    5 ?        S<     0:00 [kworker/0:0H]
    6 ?        S      0:00 [kworker/u:0]
    7 ?        S<     0:00 [kworker/u:0H]
    8 ?        S      0:00 [migration/0]
    9 ?        S      0:00 [rcu_bh]
   10 ?        S      0:00 [rcu_sched]
   11 ?        S      0:00 [watchdog/0]
   12 ?        S<     0:00 [cpuset]
   13 ?        S<     0:00 [khelper]
   14 ?        S      0:00 [kdevtmpfs]
   15 ?        S<     0:00 [netns]
   16 ?        S      0:00 [bdi-default]
   17 ?        S<     0:00 [kintegrityd]
   18 ?        S<     0:00 [kblockd]
   19 ?        S<     0:00 [ata_sff]
   20 ?        S      0:00 [khubd]
   21 ?        S<     0:00 [md]
   22 ?        S<     0:00 [devfreq_wq]
   24 ?        S      0:00 [khungtaskd]
   25 ?        S      0:00 [kswapd0]
   26 ?        SN     0:00 [ksmd]
   27 ?        SN     0:00 [khugepaged]
   28 ?        S      0:00 [fsnotify_mark]
   29 ?        S      0:00 [ecryptfs-kthrea]
   30 ?        S<     0:00 [crypto]
   41 ?        S<     0:00 [kthrotld]
   42 ?        S      0:00 [kworker/0:2]
   45 ?        S<     0:00 [binder]
   64 ?        S<     0:00 [deferwq]
   65 ?        S<     0:00 [charger_manager]
  163 ?        S      0:00 [scsi_eh_0]
  167 ?        S      0:00 [scsi_eh_1]
  222 ?        S      0:00 [jbd2/sda1-8]
  223 ?        S<     0:00 [ext4-dio-unwrit]
  294 ?        S      0:00 upstart-file-bridge --daemon
  318 ?        S      0:00 upstart-udev-bridge --daemon
  320 ?        Ss     0:00 /sbin/udevd --daemon
  418 ?        S<     0:00 [kpsmoused]
  601 ?        S      0:00 upstart-socket-bridge --daemon
  630 ?        S<     0:00 [kworker/0:1H]
  633 ?        S<     0:00 [cfg80211]
  664 ?        S<     0:00 [hd-audio0]
  725 ?        Ss     0:00 dbus-daemon --system --fork
  733 ?        Sl     0:00 rsyslogd -c5
  749 ?        Ss     0:00 /usr/sbin/modem-manager
  750 ?        Ss     0:00 /usr/sbin/bluetoothd
  780 ?        S<     0:00 [krfcommd]
  808 ?        S      0:00 avahi-daemon: running [ashley-Sorrento.local]
  810 ?        S      0:00 avahi-daemon: chroot helper
  842 ?        Ss     0:00 /usr/sbin/cupsd -F
  856 tty4     Ss+    0:00 /sbin/getty -8 38400 tty4
  860 tty5     Ss+    0:00 /sbin/getty -8 38400 tty5
  865 ?        Ssl    0:00 NetworkManager
  869 tty2     Ss+    0:00 /sbin/getty -8 38400 tty2
  870 tty3     Ss+    0:00 /sbin/getty -8 38400 tty3
  872 tty6     Ss+    0:00 /sbin/getty -8 38400 tty6
  890 ?        Ss     0:00 /usr/sbin/cups-browsed
  899 ?        Ss     0:00 acpid -c /etc/acpi/events -s /var/run/acpid.socket
  914 ?        SLsl   0:00 lightdm
  962 ?        Ss     0:00 /bin/sh -e /proc/self/fd/9
  964 ?        S      0:00 initctl emit plymouth-ready
  969 ?        Ss     0:00 cron
  984 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/lib/policykit-1/polkitd --no-debug
  994 tty7     Ss+    0:30 /usr/bin/X :0 -core -auth /var/run/lightdm/root/:0 -n
 1090 ?        S      0:00 [flush-8:0]
 1091 ?        Ssl    0:00 whoopsie
 1102 tty1     Ss+    0:00 /sbin/getty -8 38400 tty1
 1110 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/lib/accountsservice/accounts-daemon
 1124 ?        S      0:00 [kauditd]
 1130 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/sbin/console-kit-daemon --no-daemon
 1245 ?        Ss     0:00 /sbin/wpa_supplicant -B -P /run/sendsigs.omit.d/wpasu
 1251 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/lib/upower/upowerd
 1365 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/lib/colord/colord
 1379 ?        Sl     0:00 lightdm --session-child 12 21
 1414 ?        S      0:00 /sbin/dhclient -d -sf /usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp
 1438 ?        SNl    0:00 /usr/lib/rtkit/rtkit-daemon
 1451 ?        S      0:00 /usr/sbin/dnsmasq --no-resolv --keep-in-foreground --
 1641 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/bin/gnome-keyring-daemon --daemonize --login
 1652 ?        Ssl    0:00 gnome-session --session=ubuntu
 1697 ?        Ss     0:00 /usr/bin/ssh-agent /usr/bin/dbus-launch --exit-with-s
 1700 ?        S      0:00 /usr/bin/dbus-launch --exit-with-session /usr/bin/im-
 1701 ?        Ss     0:00 //bin/dbus-daemon --fork --print-pid 5 --print-addres
 1711 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/lib/at-spi2-core/at-spi-bus-launcher
 1715 ?        S      0:00 /bin/dbus-daemon --config-file=/etc/at-spi2/accessibi
 1718 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/lib/at-spi2-core/at-spi2-registryd --use-gnome-s
 1726 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon/gnome-settings-daemon
 1738 ?        S<l    0:00 /usr/bin/pulseaudio --start --log-target=syslog
 1744 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfsd
 1750 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/lib/gvfs//gvfsd-fuse -f /run/user/ashley/gvfs
 1765 ?        Rl     1:24 compiz
 1772 ?        S      0:00 syndaemon -i 1.0 -t -K -R
 1777 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/lib/dconf/dconf-service
 1780 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon/gnome-fallback-mount-h
 1781 ?        Sl     0:01 nautilus -n
 1782 ?        Sl     0:00 nm-applet
 1783 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/lib/policykit-1-gnome/polkit-gnome-authenticatio
 1796 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfs-udisks2-volume-monitor
 1800 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/lib/udisks2/udisksd --no-debug
 1807 ?        S      0:00 /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconf/gconfd-2
 1812 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfs-gphoto2-volume-monitor
 1816 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfs-mtp-volume-monitor
 1820 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfs-afc-volume-monitor
 1839 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfsd-burn --spawner :1.8 /org/gtk/gvfs
 1844 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfsd-trash --spawner :1.8 /org/gtk/gvf
 1850 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/bamf/bamfdaemon
 1857 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfsd-metadata
 1859 ?        Ss     0:00 /bin/sh -c /usr/bin/gtk-window-decorator
 1860 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/bin/gtk-window-decorator
 1864 ?        Sl     0:01 /usr/lib/unity/unity-panel-service
 1866 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/hud/hud-service
 1879 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/indicator-sound-service
 1882 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/lib/indicator-messages/indicator-messages-servic
 1883 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/indicator-bluetooth/indicator
 1885 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/indicator-sync/indicator-sync
 1887 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/indicator-datetime-service
 1890 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/indicator-application-service
 1891 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/indicator-printers-service
 1893 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/lib/indicator-session/indicator-session-service
 1932 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/lib/evolution/evolution-source-registry
 1950 ?        Sl     0:00 telepathy-indicator
 1957 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/lib/telepathy/mission-control-5
 1966 ?        Sl     0:00 zeitgeist-datahub
 1967 ?        Sl     0:00 gnome-screensaver
 1973 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/bin/zeitgeist-daemon
 1982 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/lib/zeitgeist/zeitgeist-fts
 1989 ?        S      0:00 /bin/cat
 2001 ?        Sl     0:01 /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/unity-lens-applications/unity
 2003 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/unity-lens-files/unity-files-
 2005 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/unity-lens-friends
 2007 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/unity-lens-music/unity-music-
 2011 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/bin/python3 /usr/lib/unity-lens-photos/unity-len
 2012 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/unity-lens-video/unity-video-
 2013 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/unity-lens-shopping/unity-sho
 2069 ?        S      0:00 sh -c /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libproxy/0.4.7/pxgsetti
 2070 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libproxy/0.4.7/pxgsettings or
 2075 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/bin/python3 /usr/lib/unity-lens-files/unity-scop
 2076 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/unity-lens-video/unity-scope-
 2083 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/unity-lens-music/unity-musics
 2106 ?        S      0:00 sh -c /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libproxy/0.4.7/pxgsetti
 2107 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libproxy/0.4.7/pxgsettings or
 2129 ?        S      0:00 sh -c /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libproxy/0.4.7/pxgsetti
 2130 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libproxy/0.4.7/pxgsettings or
 2147 ?        Sl     0:00 update-notifier
 2159 ?        S      0:00 /sbin/udevd --daemon
 2160 ?        S      0:00 /sbin/udevd --daemon
 2165 ?        Sl     0:20 /usr/lib/firefox/firefox
 2181 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/lib/libunity-webapps/unity-webapps-service
 2221 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/deja-dup/deja-dup-monitor
 2243 ?        S      0:00 [kworker/0:1]
 2269 ?        S      0:00 [kworker/u:2]
 2271 ?        S      0:00 [kworker/0:0]
 2288 ?        S      0:00 [kworker/0:3]
 2294 ?        Ss     0:00 /bin/sh -c gnome-terminal
 2295 ?        Sl     0:00 gnome-terminal
 2301 ?        S      0:00 gnome-pty-helper
 2303 pts/0    Ss     0:00 bash
 2352 pts/0    R+     0:00 ps ax
```

output of service --status-all

```
ashley@ashley-Sorrento:~$ service --status-all
 [ ? ]  acpi-support
 [ ? ]  acpid
 [ ? ]  alsa-restore
 [ ? ]  alsa-store
 [ ? ]  anacron
 [ - ]  apparmor
 [ ? ]  apport
 [ ? ]  avahi-cups-reload
 [ ? ]  avahi-daemon
 [ ? ]  bluetooth
 [ - ]  bootlogd
 [ - ]  brltty
 [ ? ]  console-font
 [ ? ]  console-setup
 [ ? ]  cron
 [ ? ]  cups
 [ ? ]  cups-browsed
 [ ? ]  dbus
 [ ? ]  dmesg
 [ ? ]  dns-clean
 [ ? ]  failsafe-x
 [ ? ]  friendly-recovery
 [ - ]  grub-common
 [ ? ]  hostname
 [ ? ]  hwclock
 [ ? ]  hwclock-save
 [ ? ]  irqbalance
 [ - ]  kerneloops
 [ ? ]  killprocs
 [ ? ]  kmod
 [ ? ]  lightdm
 [ ? ]  modemmanager
 [ ? ]  network-interface
 [ ? ]  network-interface-container
 [ ? ]  network-interface-security
 [ ? ]  network-manager
 [ ? ]  networking
 [ ? ]  networking.dpkg-new
 [ ? ]  ondemand
 [ ? ]  plymouth
 [ ? ]  plymouth-log
 [ ? ]  plymouth-ready
 [ ? ]  plymouth-splash
 [ ? ]  plymouth-stop
 [ ? ]  plymouth-upstart-bridge
 [ ? ]  pppd-dns
 [ ? ]  procps
 [ ? ]  pulseaudio
 [ ? ]  rc.local
 [ ? ]  resolvconf
 [ ? ]  rfkill-restore
 [ ? ]  rfkill-store
 [ - ]  rsync
 [ ? ]  rsyslog
 [ + ]  saned
 [ ? ]  sendsigs
 [ ? ]  setvtrgb
 [ ? ]  speech-dispatcher
 [ - ]  stop-bootlogd
 [ - ]  stop-bootlogd-single
 [ - ]  sudo
 [ ? ]  udev
 [ ? ]  udev-fallback-graphics
 [ ? ]  udev-finish
 [ ? ]  udevmonitor
 [ ? ]  udevtrigger
 [ ? ]  ufw
 [ ? ]  umountfs
 [ ? ]  umountnfs.sh
 [ ? ]  umountroot
 [ - ]  unattended-upgrades
 [ - ]  urandom
 [ ? ]  whoopsie
 [ - ]  x11-common
```

Comment: Hi! Could you provide us with a little more information about your system, please? For example: Harddrive, Ram, CPU, are all apps taking long to start? You could also have a look at "top" to see what processes are keeping your system busy and start digging from there (iotop, htop, atop, ...)

Comment: i dont know much but my harddrive is empty, 2048MB DDR2 RAM and an intel celeron C900 CPU, does that help? all apps lag when opening them, it seems like nothing will run smoothly at all

Comment: I was more thinking of the type of harddrive and size, but empty is a good start. 2G of RAM and a Celeron c900 are, of course,  for today's systems and applications quite weak. So using all the defaults might be a bit too much for your computer. Meaning you might have to do some optimisation, like tweaking or changing your window manager (e.g., to xfce), disable some graphic effects, disable unwanted services. And limit yourself to run only single and lightweight applications, for video display "vlc" has proven to be quite good. In your browser limit the number of concurrent tabs and windows.

Comment: You could post the output of "ps ax" so we can see, what is running on your computer. Also maybe "service --status-all", "cat /proc/meminfo" and have a look at "top" to see what is keeping your system busy most.

Answer (score 1):

After reading this review: [Ei System Sorrento 1 review](http://www.techradar.com/reviews/pc-mac/laptops-portable-pcs/laptops-and-netbooks/ei-system-sorrento-1-655866/review) of your laptop at techradar.com I got the impression that although the specs of the Ei Sorrento are OK, it is really a low-end laptop. I couldn't find any Linux drivers for your integrated SiS graphics card. Maybe you'd be better off running your original Windows on this computer.

Otherwise if you're determined to try Ubuntu, you should test it by running it from a live CD before you install anything! You have no 3D graphics support, so you'd be better off trying Xubuntu 32-bit, preferably Xubuntu 12.04 which is a Long Term Support release supported by updates until April, 2015, instead of 13.04 which is supported by updates only until January, 2014.